# Why is the Jordan-Wigner transformation an example of an S-duality?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, string-theory, spin-models, duality

The Jordan-Wigner transformation allows one to map a spin theory to a fermionic theory and, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation), it is an example of an S-duality. In turn, according to the wiki page for the [S-duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-duality); “S-duality is useful because it relates a theory with coupling constant $g$ to an equivalent theory with coupling constant $1/g$”.

Take now for example the 1D XY Heisenberg model
$$
H = J \sum_i (1+g)S_i^x S^x_{i+1} + (1-g) S_i^yS^y_{i+1}
$$
and perform a Jordan-Wigner transform:
$$
H= \frac{J}{2} \sum_i \left( f^{\dagger}_{i+1} f_i+ f_i^{\dagger} f_{i+1}+ g(f_{i+1}f_i +f^{\dagger}_i f^{\dagger}_{i+1}) \right)
$$
where can I see this $g \rightarrow 1/g$ behaviour Of the S-duality?

Thanks!

Comment: In a less strict sense, the S-duality is a duality between a strongly coupled theory and a weakly coupled one. That is certainly achieved when the Jordan-Wigner transform is applied to *certain* models, such as the XY and Ising models (which become noninteracting fermionic models). However, the Wikipedia text seems to imply it's the transformation itself that is an example of an S-duality. I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: @Anyon47 Indeed one can turn the second Hamiltonian in my answer to a non interacting fermionic Hamiltonian via a Bogoliubov transformation. This implies "$g\rightarrow 0$" in some sense. Do you mean this is an S-duality because it maps a (strongly) interacting system to a non-interacting system and that's it or does an an S-duality need to have exactly the $g\rightarrow 1/g$ behaviour it says on Wikipedia?

Comment: Yes, in some sense the second Hamiltonian in your example has $g\rightarrow 0$, where $g$ is a coupling strength in a perturbative series (i.e. it could be different from the anisotropy parameter). Hopefully someone with more expertise in this area will weigh in on whether that constitutes an S-duality or not. I will say that the BBS book (Becker, Becker & Schwarz) defines S-duality as requiring $g\rightarrow 1/g$, but based on what I've read Polchinski seems to allow for a more general duality mapping.